# AngularJS $watch called two time

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have a problem with a $watch event, in my controller I change some data like this :

```
var tab = {};
    exp.plate.experiments.forEach(function (element) {
        if (data[element.well] === true) {
            tab[element.well] = element;
        }
    });

exp.curves = tab;
```

And in a directive I watch the variable to check changes like this :

```
scope.$watch('curves', reloadChart, true);
```

And here is my reloadchart function :

```
function reloadChart() {
    if (angular.isObject(scope.curves)) {
        console.log('RELOADCHART in progress')
    }
}
```

My problem is that the reloadChart function is called two time, but the curves values in changed only once.

Why ?

Edit :

I found my error, in another directive I have a function who made a copy of the curves variable and make some changes to the copy, I did not know that angular watch is also on the variable created by copy.

=> I replace this line :

```
legend = scope.curves;
```

To this :

```
legend = angular.copy(scope.curves)
```

Comment: You could add a validation to the $watch function to only call your `reloadChart` if the new value is different from the old value. Have you tested the values that your scope.curves have each time you enter the `reloadChart` function?

Comment: I have check and the two times there is something in scope.curves and the two times it's exactly the same data, this is very strange

Comment: This is really odd. The last `$watch` parameter is the objectEquality and you're already setting to true so it's comparing object equality instead of comparing reference. I saw that in your controller you're using `exp.curves`, where are you setting the scope.curves?

Comment: I pass the exp.curves to my directive in the html with an attributes

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your problem so I've created a fiddle to try to understand it better. The following is what I'm imagining you're facing. https://jsfiddle.net/b3hw8j7x/20/

Comment: I just found my error, that was a stupid error ^^' (if you want you can check the edit)

Comment: Good to know that you've found your problem. Sorry for the mess :)

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener `fn`, you can compare the `newVal` and `oldVal`. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.
>
> [— AngularJS $rootScope/$scope API Reference - $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

```
scope.$watch('curves', reloadChart, true);

function reloadChart(newVal,oldVal) {
    if (newVal === oldVal) return;
    //ELSE
    if (angular.isObject(scope.curves)) {
        console.log('RELOADCHART in progress')
    }
}
```